# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm pulling my hair out trying to find the cause of the SqlExcpetion below. I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express and SqlDeveloper. I've looked through other posts, but so far no help.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1029)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
at com.ets.hr.dao.EmployeeDAO.createEmployee(EmployeeDAO.java:30)
at Test.main(Test.java:62)
```

Method below:

```
public void createEmployee(Employee e){
    try{
        Class.forName(oracleClass);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleUrl, "hr", "hr");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES(" +
                       e.getEmployeeId() + ", '" +
                       e.getFirstName() + "', '" +
                       e.getLastName() + "', '" +
                       e.getEmail() + "', '" +
                       e.getPhoneNumber() + "', " +
                       e.getHireDate() + ", '" +
                       e.getJobId() + "', " +
                       e.getSalary() + ", " +
                       e.getCommissionPct() + ", " +
                       e.getManagerId() + ", " +
                       e.getDepartmentId() + ")";

        s.executeQuery(query);//LINE 30 - SqlException Here
        System.out.println("Query Executed: Create Employee");
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
        ce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Employee Class:

```
package com.ets.hr.dto;

import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {

//CONSTRUCTORS
public Employee(){}

public Employee(long eId, 
                String firstName, 
                String lastName, 
                String email, 
                String phoneNumber, 
                Date hireDate, 
                String jobId, 
                double salary, 
                double commissionPct,
                long managerId,
                long departmentId){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
    this.jobId = jobId;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.commissionPct = commissionPct;
    this.managerId = managerId;
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

//instance variables (from HR.EMPLOYEE table)
private long employeeId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;
private Date hireDate;
private String jobId;
private double salary;
private double commissionPct;
private long managerId;
private long departmentId;

//GETTERS
public long getEmployeeId(){
    return this.employeeId;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return this.lastName;
}
public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}
public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return this.phoneNumber;
}
public Date getHireDate(){
    return this.hireDate;
}
public String getJobId(){
    return this.jobId;
}
public double getSalary(){
    return this.salary;
}
public double getCommissionPct(){
    return this.commissionPct;
}
public long getManagerId(){
    return this.managerId;
}
public long getDepartmentId(){
    return this.departmentId;
}

//SETTERS
public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId){
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
public void setHireDate(Date hireDate){
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
}
public void setJobId(String jobId){
    this.jobId = jobId;
}
public void setSalary(double salary){
    this.salary = salary;
}
public void setCommissionPct(double commissionPct){
    this.commissionPct = commissionPct;
}
public void setManagerId(long managerId){
    this.managerId = managerId;
}
public void setDepartmentId(long departmentId){
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public void printEmployee(){
    System.out.println("Employee ID: " + this.getEmployeeId());
    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + this.getFirstName() + this.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Employee Email: " + this.getEmail());
    System.out.println("Employee Phone: " + this.getPhoneNumber());
    System.out.println("Employee Hire Date: " + this.getHireDate());
    System.out.println("Employee Job ID: " + this.getJobId());
    System.out.println("Employee Salary: " + this.getSalary());
    System.out.println("Employee Commission Pct: " + this.getCommissionPct());
    System.out.println("Employee Manager ID: " + this.getManagerId());
    System.out.println("Employee Department ID: " + this.getDepartmentId());
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried looking at what the `query` string looks like before executing the query?

Comment: Along with the query string, posting the CREATE TABLE sql would be helpful.

Comment: First off, you should really not embed literals in your SQL statement.  There is a whole litany of reasons why that is bad.  That is what parameters are for. OK for one-off testing, but never do this in production code.    You may have some syntax-related character in one of your fields.

Comment: Vache, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Kevin, I don't have the CREATE TABLE code - I'm using the sample tables that came with SqlDeveloper.

Comment: What is the row the insert is failing on? Character encoding could be a cause. If you have non-English characters, the data in a column may be incorrectly interpreted as a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to build your own SQL string, because you have to deal with quoting and escaping (which has bitten you here).

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement` and let the JDBC API escape, quote and format (eg dates) your values *for* you:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(e.getEmployeeId(), 1);
ps.setString(e.getFirstName(), 2);
ps.setDate(e.getHireDate(), 6);
// etc - there is a setter for each basic datatype
ps.execute();
ps.close();
```

The coding is easier, and readability goes way up too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the following methods is producing a value that the database expects to be quoted/escaped (maybe it contains a comma itself, or another database special character):

```
e.getEmployeeId()
e.getHireDate()
e.getSalary()
e.getCommissionPct()
e.getManagerId()
e.getDepartmentId()
```

I'd recommend looking into the `PreparedStatement` class to help with bugs like this (as well as guarding against SQL-based security holes).

Comment: I just added in the Employee class code (includes the methods you reference). Any other thoughts?

Comment: Yes - based on the method signatures you posted, there's the chance that `hireDate` or `jobId` could be producing a `String` that's malformed for use in the database (though it's harder to tell without access to the table definition; it could in theory be another method).

To help you debug, I'd suggest what Vache mentioned above - call `System.out.println(query)` right before you call `s.executeQuery()` so you can look at exactly what's going into the d/b. The line that gets printed out right before your error should point out the error to you.

Answer (score 0):

As OldProgrammer mentions, Instead of embedding the values like this

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
String query = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES(" +
                   e.getEmployeeId() + ", '" +
                   e.getFirstName() + "', '" +
                   e.getLastName() + "', '" +
                   e.getEmail() + "', '" +
                   e.getPhoneNumber() + "', " +
                   e.getHireDate() + ", '" +
                   e.getJobId() + "', " +
                   e.getSalary() + ", " +
                   e.getCommissionPct() + ", " +
                   e.getManagerId() + ", " +
                   e.getDepartmentId() + ")";

s.executeQuery(query);
```

You could use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and then any special SQL syntax will be ignored/escaped when the values are put in. Try doing it like this

```
String query = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, e.getEmployeeId());
ps.setString(2, e.getFirstName());
//.... etc for the rest of your parameters
```